# Split one VARCHAR field that contains some double quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, csv

I'm using a stored procedure to bulk insert a large csv file into a table, all in one field that is set to `varchar(8000)`. I've had to do it this way as some of the data is enclosed in quotation marks and some are not. In SQL Server 2008 to be usable as a data file for bulk import, a CSV file must comply with the following restrictions:

- Data fields never contain the field terminator.
- Either none or all of the values in a data field are enclosed in quotation marks ("").

My data is thus:

```
Field1
"data", "data2", "data3", "data4", 123, 567, 354, 5,64,4565,54
```

Which is now in a temptable with SQL Server. How do I now clean the data and insert into a table to look like the below:  (I already have this new table setup with the correct headings)

```
Field1 
data

Field2
data 2

Field 3
data 3
```

And so on.

Ultimately it all needs to be performed in a stored procedure as it needs to be in reporting services. I've been looking at the functions, but how do I make it work when some of the fields do not have double quotes? Is the comma enough? Also is the XML function the best?

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I take the following approach to importing data:

1. Insert the table into a staging table where all the columns are character strings.
2. Copy the table from there into the appropriate table with the column types and structure that I want.

In your case, the second part of the code would be:

```
insert into FinalTable(col1, . . . )
    select (case when left(col1, 1) = '"' then replace(col1, '"', '')
                 else col1
            end),
           (case when isnumeric(col2) = 1 then cast(col2 as float)
            end),
           . . .
    from StagingTable
```

There are, no doubt, solutions in SSIS or using a format file.  I prefer a staging table approach because I find it easier to debug data issues from the database using the staging table.

Comment: Or maybe you could pre-process the csv file and remove the double quote marks before you import it? It should be easy enough to do using SED or a small C-program for instance.

Comment: Thanks Gordon I will take a look.  JPW - unfortunately pre-processig the csv file is not an option.

Comment: Hey I'm receiving the below error: The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.
The staging table has just one field called Field 1 - how does it know that after each comma it needs to go into a new field in the final table?

Comment: this is my code: insert into Final_Table(Col1, col2, col3.....col20)
select (case when left(Field1, 1) = '"' then replace(Field1, '"', '')
                 else Field1
            end),
           (case when isnumeric(Field1) = 1 then cast(Field1 as float)
            end)
  from Temp_Table

Comment: @user2470603 . . . If you put 20 columns in the `insert` statement, you need 20 columns in the `select`.  No more.  No less.  If you want two columns, than just put those two in the column list for the `insert`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply.  As I test I've change my code to this:  insert into FinalTable(Col1)
select (case when left(Field1, 1) = '"' then replace(Field1, '"', '')
                 else Field1
            end),
           (case when isnumeric(Field1) = 1 then cast(Field1 as float)
            end)
  from TempTable                                                                     But still receice an error

Comment: @user2470603 . . . That `insert` statement has only one column specified, but the `select` is returning two values.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand.  The temp table only has 1 field that contains all the data: field1